# Data is not getting inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on Flight portal. Lets assume that there are two pages (Search.php, Result.php).

In search page we will select the source,destination,date of journey..etc.(Now we will click on search button)

After clicking on the search button page will redirect to Result.php and there we will display the results.

Here before displaying the results on the page i am trying to insert those result in the database as below.

```
$q=0;
foreach($array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'] as $main)
{
    $basefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['ActualBaseFare'];
    $tax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['Tax'];
    $stax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['STax'];
    $tcharge[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TCharge'];
    $scharge[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['SCharge'];
    $totalfare[$q]=$basefare[$q]+$tax[$q]+$stax[$q]+$tcharge[$q]+$scharge[$q];
$s=0;

foreach($array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['onward']['FlightSegments']['FlightSegment'] as $array)
{
        $z1=$flightnumber[$q][$s]=$array['FlightNumber'];
        $z2=$departureloc[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureAirportName'];
        $z3=$departurecode[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureAirportCode'];
        $z4=$arrivalloc[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalAirportName'];
        $z5=$arrivalcode[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalAirportCode'];
        $z6=$departuretime[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureDateTime'];
        $z7=$arrivaltime[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalDateTime'];
        $z8=$airlinename[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineName'];
        $z9=$airlineflightnumber[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineFlightNumber'];
        $z10=$airlinecode[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineCode'];


        echo $mysql_query="insert into RviewInternationalFlight (q,s,FlightNumber,OperatingAirlineName,OperatingAirlineFlightNumber,OperatingAirlineCode,DepartureAirportName,DepartureAirportCode,ArrivalAirportName,ArrivalAirportCode,DepartureDateTime,ArrivalDateTime,ip) values('$q','$s','$z1','$z2','$z3','$z4','$z5','$z6','$z7','$z8','$z9','$z10','$ip'
)";


        mysql_query($mysql_query) or die(mysql_error());

$s++;
}
$q++;
}
```

It should work fine but i am getting the error  `MySQL server has gone away`.

At top of the page the i am connecting the database. But still why that error is coming...

Any suggestions...?

Thanks

Comment: Have you Googled the error message? The results should give you some pointers to start with.

Comment: Check out the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Have you tried asking it to send you a postcard? loljk na I had this problem once and it turns out that the server I was using was using a deprecated version of MySQL, just a simple update fixed it

Comment: @Jhon Blake I think link provided by you will help me.Thnku.

Answer (score 0):

The server connection timed out and closed the connection. By default, the connection times out after 8 hours. If you have been leaving it open that long, it's probably not a good plan. See @JohnBlake comment.

Comment: No actually for every search the database will connect. There is no chance of leaving the connection.

Comment: 8 hours is a long time for a script to run from the top to the code snippet posted in the question. However, one can use `mysql_ping()` to verify the connection and automatically reconnect if neccessary.

Comment: @Sreeram I don't think you understand my answer. The connection timed out; it's the only way to get that error.

Comment: @Lukas he could have changed a setting in a config file to change the timeout time

Comment: Actually the same code is working in Domestic Flight search. While coming to the International Search it is showing this error.

Comment: @imulsion In fact, `The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.` But there sure are more ways to get this one. See the link John provided. Sree ram's comment supports that.

Comment: @Sreeram Well then I have no idea why it is happening. Try checking the link in John Blake's comment.

Comment: @Lukas is there? Sorry. But my answer still stands.

Comment: Yes i am seeing that...Thanks for you effort.